# .class selector syntax Is NOT valid.. What is the new valid form for CSS .class selectors?

Tags: css, html

So... I'm a newbie in CSS and just a moment a go I discovered something wierd!
This is the code i wrote...

**li.list { float: left; }** ... but it did not work. If I am being to unclear let me explain.. **tag**.**class_name** is the official syntax for this type of situation! My command says that I want to change the element **li** that is a part of the class **list** so that it floats to the left of the page "viewport".

And when I changed the command to **.list li { float: left; }** it worked..

So my question is this.. Is this ( What I am experiencing ) somekind of a new update to css that I don't know about even tho I have been looking for answer elsewere.. or is it just for me???!

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding how classes work in CSS. If `.list li` works, then you have applied the class to the list tag, not to the list item (`<li>`) tag itself. Your `<li>` element is not “part of” any class; it has a class applied to it. At least, it does if your HTML has `<li class="list">`. If you have `<ul class="list"><li>...</li></ul>`, then the list tag (`<ul>`) has a class applied to it, and the list item tag does not.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Your comment is confusing, even to a frontend web developer like myself

Comment: Please provide an example of the markup that you used. It seems you don't understand how some CSS selectors work and the differences between them because you are mixing up two completely different selections in the question

Comment: @ZachSaucier What’s confusing about it? I was trying to say more or less the same thing you did: that the two selections are completely different, and that there seems to be some confusion over which element actually has the class applied to it (viz., if the `li` element has the class applied to it, then `li.list` **does** work and `.list li` doesn’t; but if it’s the containing `ul` or `ol` element that has the class applied, then `.list li` works and `li.list`doesn’t).

Comment: This is not a graphic design question - This would probably be better in the main Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you've accidentally created two accounts, please see https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to see how to get them merged into one

Answer (score 1):

I highly suggest looking up the entry on CSS selectors on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors) and looking up a reference chart such as the one on [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). These haven't changed much since the first iteration of CSS.

By taking the example you've quoted here,

- `li.list` selects all `<li>` elements with `class="list"` (*.class* selector)
- `.list li` selects all `<li>` elements that are children of any element with a `class="list"` (*element element* selector)